# Is there a name for the algebraic structure formed from the power set of a structure with the operation induced by that power set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I'm currently analysing the nature of the following construct:

Let $(S, \circ)$ be an algebraic structure of one operation (of arbitrary nature: magma, semigroup, or group, and so on).

Let $\mathcal P (S)$ denote the power set of $S$.

Let $\circ _{\mathcal P}$ denote the operation induced on $\mathcal P (S)$ by the operation $\circ$.

That is:

$\forall A, B \in \mathcal P (S): A \circ _{\mathcal P} B := \{a \circ b: a \in A, b \in B\}$

The algebraic structure $(\mathcal P (S), \circ _{\mathcal P})$ has properties dependent upon the nature of $S$ and $\circ$ which are up for exploration.

The question is: does this structure $(\mathcal P (S), \circ _{\mathcal P})$ have a name?

At the moment I am calling it:

"the algebraic structure formed from the power set of $S$ under the operation induced on $\mathcal P (S)$ by $\circ$"

which gets old very quickly.

Is there an accepted term for this? I have only ever encountered it in passing before now, so have never thought about giving it a name -- but as I want to report on a whole heap of properties of such a construct, I would really appreciate knowing a considerably shorter way to refer to it.

EDIT: While I have had a few suggestions as to what to call the *operation* (I'm fine with that, it's the "operation induced by $\circ$", which is not too much of a mouthful -- oh, and thank you to Roselyn Baxter for "Minkowki sum"), what I would *really* like would be a compact term for the *algebraic structure* for which $\circ _{\mathcal P}$ is the operation and for which the power set of the original set is the underlying set.

Comment: If $\circ$ is addition then the operation on the power set is sometimes called the 'Minkowski sum'. As far as I know there are no standard names for other examples, so you could call it the 'Minkowski operation of $\circ$'.

Comment: I would just call it the induced operation with a single sentence defining what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is a semigroup, then the semigroup ${\cal P}(S)$ you describe is often called the *power semigroup* of $S$, although the term *global semigroup* is also sometimes used in the literature.